# How long does compiling mxnet take?

Tags: python, python-2.7, github, compilation, mxnet

I was following the repository for [RoITransformer_DOTA](https://github.com/dingjiansw101/RoITransformer_DOTA).
There I first cloned the mxnet repository and then used the following command to compile it

```
make -j $(nproc) USE_OPENCV=1 USE_BLAS=openblas USE_CUDA=1 USE_CUDA_PATH=/usr/local/cuda USE_CUDNN=1
```

It's been 3 hours since then. I am pretty new to this so I wanted to ask that if something's wrong or does it normally take this long to compile mxnet.
Note: I didn't checkout at branch 998378a. Previously when I checked out I took mere 5-6 minutes.

Comment: An update, it ended after 3 more hours(Total 6 hours), and gave me an error for python 2.7. I will try installing python 3 and compiling mxnet again.